# Intercept clicks, make some calls then resume what the click should have done before

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers, click

Good day all, I have this task to do:

there are many, many many webpages, with any kind of element inside, should be inputs, buttons, links, checkboxes and so on, some time there should be a javascript that could handle the element behaviour, sometimes it is a simple `<a href="...">...</a>` link.

i have made a little javascript that intercepts all the clicks on clickable elements:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=checkbox], button, a').bind('click', function(evt, check) {

        if (typeof check == 'undefined'){
            evt.preventDefault();
                console.log("id:"+ evt.target.id+", class:"+evt.target.class+", name:"+evt.target.name);
                console.log (check);            
            $(evt.target).trigger('click', 'check');
        }
    });
});
```

the logic is: when something is cllicked, I intercept it, preventDefault it, make my track calls and then resme the click by trigger an event with an additional parameter that will not trigger the track call again.

but this is not working so good. submit clicks seams to work, but for example clicking on a checkbox will check it, but then it cannot be unchecked, links are simply ignored, I track them (in console.log() ) but then the page stay there, nothing happens.

maybe I have guessed it in the wrong way... maybe i should make my track calls and then bind a `return true` with something like `(//...track call...//).done(return true);` or something...

anyone has some suggestions?

Comment: Is your track call synchronous or asynchronous? If it is synchronous, then there's no need to re-trigger an event or preventDefault(), because the default action will not fire until your event callback completed.

Comment: I was planning to make a simple $.get("mytrackurl");

Comment: So for a simple tracking call, I still don't see why you need to prevent default and re-trigger the event. Why doesn't just firing the $.get call inside the event handler work? Do you need to check the result of the 'get' call?

Comment: well, my doubt was primary to let the get call has the time to contact the server, I don't want to start the call, and truncate it because of a link that want to go elsewhere... or a submit or whatever.
If you think it is safe just to stay inside the handler, well, I'll try it :D

Comment: ok, I'm giving a look to SJAX (syncronous javascript calls). maybe it is the way, in that case i can not use the preventdefault, which is the main problem here.

Comment: Hm, I don't quite know what you mean by truncate the call, sorry :). To my understanding the call to the server should be made instantly and thus, you should see the log data on the server and be able to process it. The only consequence for links would be that you cannot send any responses from the server, because the page will have been unloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wanted to wait with the click event until you finished with your tracking call, you could probably do something like this. Here's an example for a link, but should be the same for other elements. The click event in this example fires after 2seconds, but in your case `link.click()` would be in the `done()` method of the ajax object.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="myl">google</a>

var handled = {};
$("#myl").on('click', function(e) {
   var link = $(this)[0];
   if(!handled[link['id']]) {
      handled[link['id']] = true;
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      //simulate async ajax call
      window.setTimeout(function() {link.click();}, 2000);
   } else {
      //reset
      handled[link['id']] = false;
   }
});
```

**EDIT**

So, for your example, this would look something like this

```
var handled = {};
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=checkbox], button, a').bind('click', function(evt) {
    if(!handled[evt.target.id]) {
      handled[evt.target.id] = true;
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.stopPropagation();
      $.ajax({
         url: 'your URL',
         data: {"id" : evt.target.id, "class": evt.target.class, "name": evt.target.name},
         done: function() {
            evt.target.click();
         }
      });
    } else {
      handled[evt.target.id] = false;          
    }
});
```

Comment: you got exactly the logic I was trying to create. I've already done something really similar to this in the mean time, so i'll accpet the answer, really thanks.